# WooCommerce Hook into Category Info

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been doing research for a couple of hours and going nowhere. Perhaps It's that I don't even know what I'm searching for.

I have a WooCommerce site running on Flatsome's latest version (Theme.)

I'm simply trying to get the category link for each item in the loop and make a CTA button to open the category. This is a widget on the homepage on flatsome.

```
function ill_category_button() {
     $link = "#";
     echo '<div class="add-to-cart-button"><a href="" . $link . "" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="386934" class=" add_to_cart_button product_type_variable button primary is-flat mb-0 is-small">Open Collection</a></div>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'ill_category_button');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product category is passed to your function as a parameter, which you can then use to grab the link using `get_term_link()`.

```
function ill_category_button( $category ) {
     $link = get_term_link( $category->term_id);
     echo '<div class="add-to-cart-button"><a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="386934" class=" add_to_cart_button product_type_variable button primary is-flat mb-0 is-small">Open Collection</a></div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'ill_category_button');
```